# Python Question - how do I extract a part of a string

Tags: python

I'm building a tool in python and for that I have a question:

I have a string such as "Denver.dwg Group Layer\Denver.dwg Annotation".

How do I assign to a variable (for later print) only the first part of the string, "Denver.dwg" ?? I need to provide a general solution, as the city name differs from case to case (it might be shorter or longer) and so counting the places until the g of dwg (10 places) won't help.

(I'm writing the python tool for arcgis 9.3.1)

Comment: This is a legitimate question, and I think many readers might be interested in the answer, but is it really an appropriate one for this site?  It has nothing to do with GIS.

Comment: I thought about it but as I am building a GIS tool I decided to go with it and ask. But if more people think like you, i'd "accept the verdict" and move it or such.

Comment: It's not a GIS question, but I think it's a question that other GIS users will have.  I would probably lean towards not closing it and providing links to other resources, such as existing stackoverflow.com questions or online tutorials.  If it is closed, I think the question will popup again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code below searches for the first occurence of the ".dwg" string and assigns a new substring (containing characters up to and including that occurence).

```
text = "Denver.dwg Group Layer\\Denver.dwg Annotation"
ext = ".dwg"

fileNameOnly = text[:text.find(ext) + len(ext)]
print fileNameOnly
```

This is very basic Python string manipulation. There are loads of quick references which will help you with these most commonly used functions, for example [Python Basics](http://www.astro.ufl.edu/~warner/prog/python.html), Section 5: Strings.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use this string.find method, see my example below.

```
s = 'Denver.dwg Group Layer/Denver.dwg Annotation"'

# this returns lowest index of first occurence of dwg
# in this case 7
idx = s.find('dwg')
print idx

# take this index and add 3 for 'dwg'
# get desired string
subs = s[:idx+3]
print subs
```

Comment: Why would someone post almost identical answer to one already posted?

Comment: If you look at when the two answers were posted, you'll see they were posted at pretty much the same time- so the second person probably didn't see yours...

Answer (score 0):

str = "Denver.dwg Group Layer\Denver.dwg Annotation"

you can use split

- c = str.split("\\")

['Denver.dwg Group Layer', 'Denver.dwg Annotation']

the result is a **list**

d = c[0].split(".") # first term of the list ie 'Denver.dwg Group Layer'

['Denver', 'dwg Group Layer']

d[0] # first term of the list

'Denver'

- or e = str.split(" ")

['Denver.dwg', 'Group', 'Layer\Denver.dwg', 'Annotation']

- or f  = str.split(" ")[0]

'Denver.dwg'

and

g  = f.split(".")

['Denver', 'dwg']

g[0]

'Denver'

look at [Dive Into Python](http://diveintopython.org/native_data_types/joining_lists.html)